# WSUS not detecting computers

Tags: wsus

Hi I have followed the online tutorial from Microsoft Technet and successfully installed an configured WSUS 3.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2008 x64. I also set up a new GPO for use with WSUS and set the required policies, however the WSUS service does not detect any computers in the Domain which obviously need updates. Can anyone help please? I have also whitelisted the server ip on port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) through Pfsense firewall. Thanks

Comment: Have you run wuauclt.exe /detectnow on the client ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of possible issues here:

- Is the WSUS actually operating on the defaults ports as you say ? It could be using the alternate config.
- The pfSense suggest the WSUS server is in another subnet as the clients. Are you sure the URL used in the policy is actually valid from the clients perspective ?
- Is the policy really deployed to the clients ? Check if the registry keys are created on a client computer. GPUPDATE /FORCE is your friend.
- On a client run "wuauclt /DetectNow" from a command prompt. Check WindowsUpdate.log (in C:\Windows or c:\Winnt) to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

One small update, sometimes the SUS server isn’t detected by just putting the address of the SUS server into the server location in the GPO. You sometimes need to add the default port of the SUS site that’s automatically created in IIS. For example, the default port is http:// wsus:8530, so you’ll need to put that in there instead of just http:// wsus. I discovered this when my SUS server was Server 2012 and IIS 8. I hope this helps some of you.

For the visually oriented folks, I took some screenshots of what I was talking about here:

http://danblee.com/wsus-not-detecting-clients-and-not-listing-computers/

Answer (score 0):

If you were templating your servers without running `sysprep` afterwards you may try to generate new Client ID. Use this [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-WSUSClientFix-fd29e1a8) for automation.